# whit criteria builder who to find whit a key in key array on postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria

Hello everybody and thanks for the time you take to answer me .

in my job i supose to implement a way find one id in array of id

i try to reproduce someting like this but in java hibernate + criteria in postgreSQL i don't understand the documentation and im do java for only 3 month

The sql request i try to reproduce look like this: .

`SELECT * FROM commercial_information ci WHERE 'f93064da-5089-4591-a2ed-5f86786daba3' = ANY (ci.prescriber_ids);`

and one of my filter is describe like this :

```
protected Predicate simpleUuidCriteria(SimpleFilter<UUID> simpleFilter, Path<UUID> path, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    if (getSimpleFilterValue(simpleFilter) != null) {
        if (EQUALS.equals(simpleFilter.getMatchMode())) {
            return builder.equal(path, getSimpleFilterValue(simpleFilter));
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

One of my idea was to change every array entry in string and find on it like sql function
but isn't working to .
i think i don't understant this langage

i try to filter on id in sql column where i have an array of id .
but i don't understand who to use  keyword ANY in my case

Comment: *but isn't working* is not an error description. Please describe yor problem in detail.

Comment: Also add sample data and expected rsult

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same type of problem here is a nice [tutorial](https://aregall.tech/hibernate-6-custom-functions) by **Arnau Aregall**.

This helped me a lot